# What can be said about the integral part of $(a+\sqrt{b})^n $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

If an irrational number of the form $a+\sqrt{b}$ is raised to the power $n$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, what can be said about the integral part of the resulting number? For instance, is it an even number? If yes what are the conditions on $n$? If odd, what are the conditions?

I think I should start from considering $(a+\sqrt{b})^n= p+q$ where p is an integer and q is a proper fraction. I don't know how to proceed further. Please help. And also suggest a website that can give more of such properties.

Comment: Are a and b boh integers? Is b assumed to not be a perfect square?

Comment: Start with the binomial formula. Which terms in the expansion are integers, and which are not?

Comment: OK... So integral part comes out to be nC0 a^n + nC2 a^(n-1) b^2 + nC4 ... And so on... How do I know if this integral part is an even number or an odd number..???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach to the case of $0 < (a-\sqrt b) < 1$:

If $0<f<1$ and $r+f \in \Bbb Z$ for some $r \in \Bbb R$, then $r+f =\left\lfloor r+1 \right\rfloor $.

$(a+\sqrt b)^n + (a - \sqrt b)^n \in \Bbb Z$ by the binomial theorem and is the integral part of $(a+\sqrt b)^n +1$. It is clearly always even and the required quantity is odd.

If $-1 <f = (a-\sqrt b) < 0$, then $r+f \in \Bbb Z$ means that $r+f = \left\lfloor  r \right\rfloor $. Now, $$\left\lfloor (a+\sqrt b)^n \right\rfloor = (a+\sqrt b)^n + (a - \sqrt b)^n$$ and has the opposite parity of n.

This is because $f^n$ alternates from positive to negative( that is, from the first case to second case).

Comment: I assume you intend $f=(a-\sqrt{b})^n$. If $0\lt f\lt1$ then $(a+\sqrt{b})^n+(a-\sqrt{b})^n$ is even, but that means that $\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{b})^n\right\rfloor=(a+\sqrt{b})^n+(a-\sqrt{b})^n-1$ is odd. Furthermore, it would be nice to know what happens when $-1\lt f\lt0$

Comment: You probably meant $-1\lt f=(a-\sqrt{b})\lt0$ in your post. However, in that case, the parity of $\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{b})^n\right\rfloor$ alternates.

Comment: You are correct once again, I really should think through more before posting an answer. I will delete my comments here, it's starting to get messy.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that $b$ is not a perfect square.

In the case that $|a-\sqrt{b}|\lt1$, this can be answered using sequences satisfying a [Linear Recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). Both $(a+\sqrt{b})^n$ and $(a-\sqrt{b})^n$ satisfy the linear recurrence
$$
u_n=2au_{n-1}+(b-a^2)u_{n-2}\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, $u_n=(a+\sqrt{b})^n+(a-\sqrt{b})^n$ also satisfies $(1)$. Furthermore, $u_0=2$ and $u_1=2a$. Thus, according to $(1)$ $u_n$ is always an even integer and $|(a-\sqrt{b})^n|\lt1$ tends to $0$.

Thus, if $n$ is even or $a^2\gt b$,
$$
\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{b})^n\right\rfloor=u_n-1\text{ is odd}\tag{2}
$$
If $n$ is odd and $a^2\lt b$,
$$
\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{b})^n\right\rfloor=u_n\text{ is even}\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $0 < a - \sqrt{b} < 1$, then

$$\left\lfloor\left(a + \sqrt{b}\right)^n\right\rfloor = 2 \left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 1 & a \end{bmatrix}^n\right)_{1,1} - 1$$

(Eigenvalue decomposition shows why.)

So if you want to ask "is this even", then the answer is "never"...it is 1 less than an even number.

You can also do the matrix computations $\pmod m$ , for example $m=10^z$, to find the last $z$ digits.

Comment: The answer for $-1\lt a-\sqrt{b}\lt0$ is not too much harder. Then $\left\lfloor(a+\sqrt{b})^n\right\rfloor$ is even if $n$ is odd and vice-versa.

Comment: @robjohn Opposite parity, interesting.  I was actually trying to think of a way to extend it to $L-1 < a - \sqrt b < L$ though, hmm.

Comment: I have looked a little bit into the case where $|a-\sqrt{b}|\gt1$, and it is definitely not as well behaved as when $|a-\sqrt{b}|\lt1$.